# Axios params not appending correctly to URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, statamic

I'm trying to use params for a post request using Axios. However, when I check the XHR in Chrome, the params don't seem to be appended to the URL.

If I do this, it works:

```
axios.post('/!/Like/like?id=' + this.id + '&_token=' + this.csrf_token)
```

But if I try this, I get an error:

```
axios.post('/!/Like/like', {
    params: {
        id: this.id,
        _token: this.csrf_token
    }
})
```

In other words, the url needs to be:

```
/!/Like/like?id=1234&_token=zYXW-123
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [second parameter](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) in `axios.post` is the data. If you wanted to post the way you are doing here, you would need to pass your params as the third argument.

```
axios.post('/!/Like/like', "", {
    params: {
        id: this.id,
        _token: this.csrf_token
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, are you missing a parenthesis at the end?

Comment: @ChrisBurton Yup, I sure am.

Comment: Also, the second argument `null` throws an error for me however, adding an empty space `''` worked perfectly.

Comment: @ChrisBurton Do you mean an empty string?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Empty string is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks @Bert -- exactly what I needed!

Comment: But why this works? it expects data as second parameter, and you put parameters as third argument as config. Very confusing.

Comment: @AlexanderKim The [`params` in the config section](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) are not the data. They are query string parameters.

Comment: Ah, clear now. `params` in a config section === query string parameters, if i pass data as second, it will be as json object in a body, right?

Comment: @AlexanderKim Right!